# How do I find if the file MyFile.03 is in the folder MyTmpFolder?

Tags: c#, winforms, file-io

How do I find if the file `MyFile.03` is in the folder `MyTmpFolder` using C# and Winforms?

Comment: what is meant by .02, is it file extension or part of filename?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
System.IO.File.Exists("MyTempFolder\\MyFile.02");
```

Answer (score 2):

System.IO.File [] files=Directory.GetFiles(dirpath);

foreach(File f1 in files)
{
  if(f1.SubString(0,f1.lastIndexOF('.'))=="MyFile.02")
{
File myFile=f1;
}
}

Answer (score 1):

The `System.IO` namespace contains members to help us work with input and output operations (a category which file operations fall under), so using the `Path` class we can manipulate file and folder paths and using the `File` class we can operate on files - this ought to do the trick for you:

```
using System.IO;

var exists = File.Exists(Path.Combine(MyTmpFolder, MyDesiredFile));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bool doesExist = File.Exists("MyTmpFolder\\MyFile.02");
```